# TouchID not filling passwords on Safari and just showing passwords stored inside Safari, not Keychain

Tags: safari, password, keychain, big-sur, touch-id

I am using BigSur for the first time today, after unboxing a new iMac M1.

I migrated all my stuff from an old iMac with Catalina, to this one, using a time machine backup.

The new machine is working well but everything related to passwords is a mess.

I have been using macOS for 15 years. I have billions of passwords for websites on keychain.

Now, on this new machine, when I visit a site that requires username/password, the field username appears filled but when I click on the password field, I am offered the option to unlock the passwords using touchID. This feature fails 100% of the time. If instead of using TouchID I type my mac password I see only the passwords stored inside safari, not those on Keychain. But the keychain passwords are there.

Any way to make this work as before?

Answer (score 0):

Having done this only last week - it is supposed to work. It does here.

Having also had multiple issues with Time Machine recently, I could make one suggestion - but it will take several hours… Set the Mac up again from scratch & at the point it asks about Migration, migrate directly from the other Mac, 'live' across ethernet, rather than from Time Machine. I've had several occasions recently where that fixed general 'weirdness'.

At Migrate, you go to the old Mac & run Migration Assistant [in Utilities]. The new Mac will then see it & start to set up from there, similar to from Time Machine. You will essentially be locked out of both Macs until it is complete.

Note that Recovery procedures are different on an M1 Mac, so print this page [or access it from your phone] before you start, just in case. - https://support.apple.com/guide/mac-help/mchl82829c17/mac

Comment: I have managed to force the old mac to dump all keychain to iCloud and now the passwords stored on keychain appear on the new mac. But the problem persists, using the finger just makes the touchID dismiss and no password appears.

Comment: Not sure what else to suggest, I'm afraid. I've been doing a lot of Mac shuffling this past week, since we got the M1 all the others are being moved up a slot with the oldest about to be retired. Mainly I've been successful with the 'live' migrate… but not 100%. Some bits do seem hit & miss.

Comment: Unfortunately the new iMac is already too different in terms of files, so I will be sad if I have to restore it to two days ago... I agree with you, this M1 mac plus BigSur is a source of little weirdnesses. One thing I find outrageous is BigSur telling me, the first time I opened Safari after the first boot of the new mac, that Safari needs Rosetta? What? No time to make Safari M1 Compatible?

Comment: Get Info on it. Safari v14.1.1 here, has checkbox for rosetta but running without it.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for @Tetsujin but I have chosen to opt for the brute force method and reinstalled BigSur on a two days old machine and all the problems were solved.

It is a shame how a brand new machine already comes with a lot of little glitches.